# Hibernate 4.3.1 JPA How to start new Thread injecting EntityManager from Action?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

It seems my application is leaking database connections, although I'm specifying the following in persistence.xml :

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
```

I use Spring 3.2.7 to manage Connections too, but only for the web part. The system executes a business process diagramam, and at this part it acquires connections this way:

```
EntityManagerFactory emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("servicos");

em = emFactory.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

No matter what value I set to release_mode at persistence.xml the connection won't return too pool, if I don't close the connection with

```
emFactory.close()
```

The connections sum up to 100 and I end up with

```
ERROR [SqlExceptionHelper] FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
```

In Postgres, SELECT current_query FROM pg_stat_activity; shows

```
<IDLE>
<IDLE> in transaction
...
```

Hibernate log shows

```
INFO [DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
```

Shouldn't the connection be returned automatically after commit ? Maybe I should inject the EntityManagerFactory into the PBM executor Thread with Spring. I tryed annotating a method it with @PersistenceUnit but it didn't work, this works only if the Action class has a method annotated. Is it safe to pass the EntityManagerFactory injected into Action to the Thread before starting it ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Spring why are you creating a `EntityManagerFactory` yourself and also why are you managing your transactions yourself? In general you want to be using a connection pool so connection will be checked out at the start of your program and returned at the end, that isn't a leak but by design.

Comment: Well, I got this code from some one else. Some times we just want to inject our DAOs using spring beans, but other times we want to control Threads more tightly, sharing connections among them. If I use Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory the hibernate relase_mode configuration won't apply ? Because release_mode 'after_transaction' should return connection to pool automatically.

Comment: I mean, hibernate has a default built-in connection pool right ? But it should manage this cycle automatically, not to wait for me to close de EntityManagerFatory

Comment: If you are mixing strategies it is even worse you might up ending with duplicate instances, multiple connection pools etc. I don't really see why you would need to mess around with the EMF yourself if you already have Spring. Not to mention that basically the whole tx management (with or without Spring) is highly thread based, sharing connections (or `EntityManager`s) between threads is generally not advised. But I probably don't understand your problem, a connection pool keeps connections open all the time, it doesn't close them, connections only return to the pool.

Comment: You mean I have to call emFactory.close() to return the connection to pool ? I know the connections are not returning bacause I get `too many clients already` errors.

Comment: The problem, imho, lies else where. I really don't get the need for manual use of the `EntityMangerFactory` why isn't it possible to use the Spring Managed one? You are only adding complexity here. You might also run into trouble as if you do things wrong you end up with multiple instances of the `EntityManagerFactory` each with its own pool of connections.

Comment: Hey, M.Deinum, I'm trying to do what you say, to let spring handle all EntityManagers and EntityManagerFactory. The problem is the web application start a new Thead at some point, this would be the BPM executor. I tryed using @PersistenceUnit to inject the EntityManagerFactory but it's not working. Could you create an answer showing how to do this ? Thank you a lot.